# Postfix with Relay and fetchmail

Tags: email, postfix, fetchmail

I have a server with Zarafa, Postfix and fetchmail.
I have a local domain: mylocaldomain.com

The local domain is configured on my server as mydomains on postfix. So every mail to @mylocaldomain.com will be deliverd to my postfix which delivers it to zarafa if the mailbox is present.

Now I have a user where I need to configure a gmail.com address as primary Mailaddress.
For sending mails I have configured a sender dependent relay within postfix which is working fine.
My problem is receiving mails. I have configured fetchmail for polling the mails from gmail. 
I can´t configure gmail.com as mydomains on postfix because if I do so I cant send mails to other gmail.com users as postfix can´t find them local.

Now when fetchmail gets the mails from gmail they are all redirected to gmail.com again. The problem is that postfix doesn´t try to deliver the mail to the local user which has the gmail.com as primaryAddress.

Is there anything I can do to get this working?